# How to make set be silent after saving model for first time

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js and rails.  When backbone.js saves a model for the first time rails responds with the new id and backbone.js does a set on the model with the new id.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41

My problem is I can't make that set be silent.  That set calls a change event which causes my view to render.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass an option in the save method to not trigger any events

```
model.save(null, { silent: true })
```